# Javascript - Get external IP address from request made on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I am currently in the process of developing a feature that that calls out to an external service to get location information based on the client's IP.

In my express node server, I am pulling the ip with `req.ip`, which from what I've read elsewhere is the correct way to do it. However, because I am running the server / client locally, the IP address on the request is my local host.

Is there anyway to make the request from my client, which is running locally, to put my external IP into the request so I can validate that my full feature is working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to your server with your public IP rather than localhost

Comment: Some more details on exactly how to accomplish this would be killer

Comment: I don't know how you implement it on your app, but if you connect to your server from a browser just type your IP and port instead of localhost.

Comment: Type `ipconfig /all`  on Windows or `ifconfig -a` on Unix to get your local IP address.  On most home networks it will be something like `192.168.x.y` or `10.0.0.x`

Comment: Which means that your geo-ip service won't be able to do much with that NAT address anyway.   So you really need to host your code on a public server instead of out of your local PC.

Comment: Or just port forward it on your router to your PC, then connect it from the public IP